# How to configure phpenv-apache-version plugin

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

To use multiple php versions on AWS EC2, I am trying to use phpenv,

I installed phpenv and it works.

Next, I got the plugin of phpenv with below command:

> $ git clone https://github.com/garamon/phpenv-apache-version
>   ~/.phpenv/plugins/phpenv-apache-version

and I try to change php version of Apache with below command:

> $ phpenv apache-version 5.6.40

But below message returns.

```
phpenv: no such command `apache-version'
```

Please tell me, how to use phpenv-apache-version plugin.

Comment: Same problem here